# Add html to transactional email

Tags: php, emails, jhtml, translation

I use Mandrill to send my transactional emails, so JMailer sends the data to Mandrill, Mandrill wraps it with a nice template and voila!

This works fine, but several of my customers have asked if I could make a button out of the LOGIN or CONFIRM links. Is there any way, without hacking the core, to add a little bit of html to the transactional text? Normally I just change the text in the language files, but that one doesnt accept HTML.

What is the best way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

There were debates arround Adding HTML support to Joomla Notification email for com_user a while ago and even there's a (closed/cancelled) [pull request](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/9634) for that. If you're willing to hack the core you can follow the code changes those are proposed in that pull request.

As an alternative to Piero suggestion, there's a component (paid one) called [E-mail Beautifier](https://techjoomla.com/products/email-beautifier) that allows you to add HTML support to Joomla notification email. I haven't tested it but you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use acymailing.

In one of the later version they include a way to override Joomla messages.

In order to make it work you first has to enable the plugin acymailingclassmail (Override Joomla mailing system plugin)

And then go to components->acymailing->newsleters ->Joomla Notificactions

where yuo can modify them.

Hope this helps you.